# How to give a unique url/id to a question posted by the user?

Tags: php, mysql

There's a form called `discussion.php`, in which a user will fill out his/her *question/discussion* and `post` it to `savedisc.php`. Some of the `savedisc.php` looks like this:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$represents = $_POST['represents'];

//connect to database

//save the content of discussion/question into the database for future use
$sql="INSERT INTO Discussion (Message, Title, Type)
VALUES
('$message','$title','$represents')";

//Display user's question/discussion again
echo $message . "<br />";
echo $title . "<br />";
echo $represents . "<br />";
```

It is not shown above, but I am saving the `id` field manually, i.e. via phpmyadmin as a auto increment and primary key of course. Therefore, all of the values in the table `Discussion` will have their own unique `id`. Once the question/discussion is saved, I want to be able to display `$title` of each question on `wb.php` as a link, which as of now looks like this(some code from `wb.php`):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Discussion ORDER BY id DESC");

//When user clicks the question/discussion Title, he/she will be directed to wbcomm.php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<a href='wbcomm.php' >{$row['Title']}</a><br />";
  }
```

Until here, everything is working smooth. However, from here on, what I'm trying to do is, when the user clicks the question/discussion title via above code, I want him/her to be directed to `wbcomm.php?id=1`, where `id=1` represents the unique id of the question/discussion. Some of the code from `wbcomm.php` is below:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
//connect to db

$wbid  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Discussion WHERE id = '$wbid' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows() > 0) {
        $discussion = mysql_fetch_object($res);
        //display member's question here:
  echo $discussion['id'] . "<br />";
  echo $discussion['Title'] . "<br />";
  echo $discussion['Type'] . "<br />";
  echo $discussion['Message'] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        // discussion does not exist with ID
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, the result is blank. I.e. the question/discussion doesn't even show up. What am I doing wrong? Is my procedure even correct?

Thank you.

Comment: To help you debug you should think about testing $res and displaying any error messages (mysql_error())

Answer (score 2):

In your `wb.php`, you create a link to `wbcomm.php` but you are not passing the ID of the discussion, so your `$wbid` will be empty. You need to pass the ID along with the link, like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<a href='wbcomm.php?id={$row['id']}' >{$row['Title']}</a><br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ID column is an autoincrement int type so you do not need to put it in quotes or escape it.  You should definitely test it to see if it's numeric, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL  `mysql_num_rows($res) > 0`